# Extracting organisms automatically from multiple BLAST outputs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bioinformatics, blast

I am currently looking for a way to extract the names of organism matches after BLASTing 20 FASTA files.  Presently, I have a for loop that I use to extract the data, read it, echo the name of the file, output it.  However, I have to manually go into each file to find the matched organism.  Is there a way I can have a cat text file made from the organisms read.

```
for file in ./*.fsa
do 
name = `echo $file | awk -F "[./]" '{print $7}'`
echo $name
blastn -db nt -query $file -out ${name}.out -remote -outfmt "6 stitle"
done
```

This will do everything I need, and since I only have 20 it's fine if not, but I'm hoping to increase the sample size and don't want to read each file for X organisms found in the outputs.

Edit:  To clarify, when I read the .out files, I am given results like so:
BLAST+ 2.X.X version

Homo sapiens (Some gene) E-value %match
Escherichia coli (some gene) E-value %match
etc.

Sequence matches, the query to the database.

What I am looking to do is to gather just the lines of the species, the e-value, and the %match.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this working? If this is bash then the spaces left and right of the `=` in the variable assignment are a syntax error.  The part about `However, I have to manually go into each file to find the matched organism.` I don't understand - can you rephrase this to make it clearer?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.